# How to add Ubuntu repositories on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, repository

I have noticed that Kubuntu (I am using 12.04 version) doesn't use exactly the same repositories that Ubuntu. Or at least, that is what I think.
For example, if I search for Steam on Muon Software Center or Muon Package Manager, I just can't find it; even if I use **sudo apt-get install steam-launcher**. But on Ubuntu I have no problem. Why?

That's why I think Ubuntu has some repositories that Kubuntu doesn't. In this case (I don't know if I'm right), how can I add this Ubuntu repositories?

Steam is only an example. There are many packages that I can't find on Kubuntu. Another example: Motorbike (a game) (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/motorbike/). **sudo apt-get install motorbike** doesn't work.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

[Kubuntu Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu): Every package in Kubuntu shares the same repositories as Ubuntu. However Steam and Motorbike aren't in the default ubuntu/kubuntu repositories. So you will have to enable the universe and multiverse repositories.

**Managing Repositories in Kubuntu**

[image: pic1]

Kubuntu uses KPackageKit for software management. To open it, click on your Kmenu, then open System Settings.

[image: pic2]

Next, select "Add and Remove Software"

[image: pic3]

Click the "Settings" button, then select "Edit Software Sources".

[image: pic4]

You will be prompted for your password in order to proceed

[image: pic5]

Next, go the the "Updates" tab. From here, you can enable/disable some of the official Ubuntu repositories and change your update settings. You should enable the universe and the multiverse repos.

Or, you could just type a line or two of commands and get the job done as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe multiverse"
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[Kubuntu repository installation instruction page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Kubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a bit different on Kubuntu 12.04. But I have the Universe and Multiverse repositories enabled, and I still can't find those packages.

Comment: Did you get the repositories added?  If the graphical interface looks different than posted, the command line will still work correctly.  Make sure you do the sudo apt-get update from the command line to refresh your sources.  An apt-get search PACKAGENAME should return information about the package you are looking to install.

Comment: I typed all the commands (adding the repo, update and upgrade), but nothing. "sudo apt-get search PACKAGENAME" doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with kubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.  I tried the terminal commands above but when I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list` the entries for `universe` and `multiverse` were incorrect.

The answer is to manually edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add the following two lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe multiverse
```

Then save and exit.  Finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
```